# How to render JSON in Grails?

Tags: grails

I have an object as,

```
def roles = account.roles
```

I want to render it in JSON format like

```
[{'value':1, 'text':'Admin'},{'value':2,'text':'Owner'}, {'value':3,'text':'Sale'}]
```

When I did the code like this, it's not working,

```
render(contentType: "text/json"){[
    "value" : roles.id,
    "text" : roles.name
]}
```

It render to the data that has wrong format like `{"value":[1,2,3],"text":["Admin","Owner","Sale"]}`

And I try like this

```
def res = roles.each(){
    ['value':it.id, 'text':it.name]
}
render res as JSON
```

It's not working either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect` instead of `each`, like

```
def res = roles.collect {['value':it.id, 'text':it.name]}
render res as JSON
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either do, render roles as JSON

Or

```
render(contentType: "application/json") {
        roles = array {
            for (r in roles) {
                role text: r.name, value:r.id
            }
        }
    }
```

See [xml and json responses](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#xmlAndJSON) section of grails user guide

Comment: For grails 3 it renders {"array":{"role":{"text":"...", "value":"...}}}